# Return when .each is completed

Tags: arrays, node.js, promise, bluebird

```
Promise.try(function (){
    return Promise.all(splitup); // [Show, me, stocks, for, Google, and, Microsoft]
}).each(function (item) { // Looping through entities, [Show] [me] [stocks] ...
    alchemyapi.entities('text', item, { 'sentiment' : 1}, function (response) {
        if(response.entities) { // An entity is found, ex. Microsoft
            if(response.entities[0].type === "Company") {
                requestBody.push(item);
                console.log("Item was found, added " + item);
            } else {
                console.log(item + " Is not a company");
            }
        } else { // no entity found for that one word
            console.log("No entity found for " + item);
        }
    });
}).then(function (response) {
    // send requestBody when loop is completed.
});
```

I start by returning an array of strings `splitup` so I can loop through each element on `line 3`.

Let's say the `splitup` array looks like: [`Apple`, `And`, `Mexico`]

`Apple` is a company, so `if(response.entities)` returns true, it then checks the JSON response to see if it is a company, that statement returns `true` and It's added to the new `requestBody` array I'm building up.

Next, the word `'And'` returns false on `if(response.entities)` so It goes to the else statement.

Next, let's pick `Mexico`, It'll return true for `if(response.entities)` but return false on `if(response.entities[0].type === "Company")`

My question is, I'd like to return the new requestBody array when It has completed looping through each item, but I'm not entirely sure how I can tell when the loop is completed, and when to return `requestBody`

Comment: I was expected that Promise.all parameter should be an array of Promise or ?

Comment: Your `alchemyapi.entities` function doesn't seem to return a promise, does it? And if it does, you'll need to `return` that from your `each` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Promise.filter`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html) instead of Promise.each. Promise.filter filters the given array to another using filterer function passed to it.

So when you encounter a company ('Apple') you `resolve` with its value, if its anything else ('Mexico' and 'And') you resolve with `false`.

```
Promise.filter(splitup, function (item) { // Looping through entities, [Show] [me] [stocks] ...
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        alchemyapi.entities('text', item, { 'sentiment' : 1}, function (response) {
            if(response.entities) { // An entity is found, ex. Microsoft
                if(response.entities[0].type === "Company") {
                    console.log("Item was found, added " + item);
                    return resolve(item);
                } else {
                    console.log(item + " Is not a company");
                    return reject(false);
                }
            } else { // no entity found for that one word
                console.log("No entity found for " + item);
                return reject(false);
            }
        });
    });
}).then(function (requestBody) {
    // send requestBody when loop is completed.
});
```

Comment: My requestBody is just empty when trying to log.

Comment: It seems like It's running that `.then` BEFORE the .filter function.

Comment: @AjaxjQuery update code. Please make sure alchemyapi.entities is getting called with proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok too late :). Here was my result:

```
var alchemyapi = require('alchemy-api');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var alchemyapi = new alchemyapi(<YOUR_KEY>);

var test = ['Microsoft', 'and', 'Apple'];

Promise.filter(test, function(item) {
  return getCompanyName(item).then(function(){
    return true;
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason.message);
    return false;
  });
}).then(function(requestBody){
  console.log(requestBody);
});

function getCompanyName(item) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    alchemyapi.entities(item, {sentiment: 1}, function (err, response) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      if (response.entities.length > 0) { // An entity is found, ex. Microsoft
        if (response.entities[0].type === "Company") {
          resolve(item);
        } else {
          reject(new Error(item + " Is not a company"));
        }
      } else { // no entity found for that one word
        reject(new Error("No entity found for " + item));
      }
    });
  });
}
```